# include Lambda in QQ plot

Tags: r

I wanted to make a QQ plot and I reached this far:

```
plot(-log(data$QQ, 10), -log(data$UNADJ,10), 
     xlab = "expected –logP values", 
     ylab = "observed –logP values"); 
abline(a = 0, b=1,col="red")
```

where:

```
QQ
7.82E-06
1.82E-05
2.16E-05
2.43E-05

UNADJ
7.82E-06
1.82E-05
2.16E-05
2.43E-05
```

this works, but I also need the lambda value, and I don't manage to integrate the function. 
could someone help me making this plot including output with lambda?

Comment: How about a small reproducible example?

Comment: Which question do you want answered:  how to find the integral (or maybe the cumulative distribution function?), or how to overlay one plot on top of the QQplot?

Comment: @ Carl Witthoft I mean the first. As far as I know Lambda is an inflation factor related to the chi-square statistic. λ is computed by taking the median of the distribution of the chi-square statistic of the data, and dividing this median by the median of the corresponding (ideal) chi-square distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar w/ the following items, found with

```
library(sos)  
???'inverse chi'
```

but you could try `dist.Inverse.ChiSquare` in **LaplacesDemon** 
or `rinvchisq` in **metrumrg**
or `InvChisquare` in **geoR**.

Maybe one of those will generate the lambda you need.